# Is it possible to select a variable that has a string assigned to it with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a recent project, I am using jQuery to detect line breaks in a paragraph, and then store the last word of each line in a variable. Is there a way to select the variable with jQuery so I can use `.hover` to change the background color of that word when I hover over it? I've searched around a bunch and haven't found an answer.

Heres my code:

```
var breakWord
var p = $('p');

p.each(function () {
    var current = $(this);
    var text = current.text();

    var words = text.split(' ');

    current.text(words[0]);
    var height = current.height();

    for (var i = 1; i < words.length; i++) {
        current.text(current.text() + ' ' + words[i]);

        if (current.height() > height) {
            height = current.height();
            breakWord = words[i - 1];
            return breakWord;
        }
    }
    return current;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a tag around the word, like `<p>` or even `<div>` with a class on it, than just change the style of that class

Answer (score 0):

If i'm understanding this right, you have a list of paragraph elements, and you store the last word from each paragraph in an array? And you want to be able to map each word in the array back to the highlighted word in the paragraph?

If thats the case, youll need some code to manage it. Youll need to track which paragraph each word came from. If it always stays in order with the array (ie element 0 is paragraph 1, element 5 is paragraph 6) then you can map it back through the index of the array element. Otherwise, its probably safer to store which paragraph the array element came with, as a property, within the array. So you can store an array of [{pSource, pText}] objects instead of a simple text array

Comment: Thank you for your response - but I'm wondering if I can put the variable in a jQuery selector like this: `$(breakWord)` and then add a hover function so every time I hover over the word it will highlight the word.

Comment: i assume you mean like in chrome, if you store an array of html elements, when you hover over one of those array items, the html element highlights in the browser? That functionality is handled by chrome's code though. I'm not a jquery expert, but it seems like a very specific thing and i highly doubt it has built in functionality for that. You would almost certainly need to write custom code to handle that

Comment: I am making a chrome extension that highlights text line by line to make reading easier. Almost like using a ruler on a book IRL. I was just wondering if I can select elements in an array compared to just selecting HTML element, so I can highlight just that word , instead of the whole P tag.

Comment: i dont think you can without custom code. If you plan to highlight a segment of text though, youll probably need a span or some kind of tag surrounding that one line so you can apply a style to it. You'll also need to handle the last line changing as they resize the window or text size. Sorry I can't be more helpful